# Error Scraping Page: Bad Response Code

Tags: facebook, api, url, metadata

I don't know what is happening with my fb app, since yesterday I have this error when I debug: http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fvimirk.com%2Ffbapp%2F

In the scraped URL it shows: 'Document returned no data'

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

That happens because Facebook cannot access your webpage. probably because of your DNS records are being blocked. or your server is behind a firewall for example your company LAN. Solution: Fix your DNS or Firewall blockages and make sure public social medias like Facebook has access to your sites.